# Iterative calculation in dplyr using result of previous calculation

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am looking to perform a calculation on a field in a dataframe with the following logic:

- If the basevalue != NA, assign the basevalue to the result
- If the basevalue == NA, take the previous result, multiply it by the multiplier field and output that as the result.

Assume that the first value is never NA so there would always be a seed value.  I would wish to perform the calculation by groups of data (dplyr::group_by)

The following code gives a reprex:

```
basevalue <- c(2,5,NA,NA,NA,NA)      
multiplier <- c(3.2,1.1,1.8,1.3,1.5,1.2)
previous_result <- c(NA,2,5,9,11.7,17.55)
result<- c(2,5,9,11.7,17.55,21.06)
logic <- c(rep("basevalue != NA, so take base value",2), rep("basevalue == NA, so take lag(result) * multiplier",4))

dfIn <- data.frame(basevalue,multiplier)
dfOut <- data.frame(basevalue,multiplier, result, previous_result, logic)
```

Is there a way to achieve this using simple dplyr / base R / tidyverse logic, or do I need to use a specialist package such as zoo?

Comment: When I try to use dplyr::mutate with lag(result) and if_else clauses, I am unable to conditionally pick up the previous result and get NAs after the first result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the `accumulate2` function from purrr, which is designed for applying this kind of recursive relationship across two vectors.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

calculate <- function(previous, basevalue, multiplier) {
  coalesce(basevalue, multiplier * previous)
}

dfIn %>%
  mutate(lst = accumulate2(basevalue, multiplier[-1], calculate),
         result = unlist(lst))
```

Two notes:

- The `multiplier[-1]` throws away the first multiplier value, since `accumulate` expects that to be one shorter than the first argument (notice that you'll never use the first multiplier value since there's no "previous" value at that point).
- The result of `accumulate2` is a list, so we add the `unlist()` to turn it into a vector.

Comment: Well... it works.  I'm not sure I really understand how, but it certainly does the job!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this with `for` loop :

```
calculate_result <- function(b, m) {
  r <- b
  inds <- which(is.na(b))
  for(i in inds) {
    r[i] <- r[i-1] * m[i]
  }
  return(r)
}
```

Applying this function with `dplyr` so that you can use `group_by` later :

```
library(dplyr)
dfIn %>% mutate(result = calculate_result(basevalue, multiplier))

#  basevalue multiplier result
#1         2        3.2   2.00
#2         5        1.1   5.00
#3        NA        1.8   9.00
#4        NA        1.3  11.70
#5        NA        1.5  17.55
#6        NA        1.2  21.06
```

Comment: This wouldn't work when applied in a `group_by()`, as the OP specifies

Comment: @DavidRobinson As far as I understand, it will. Why do you think it will not work with `group_by` ?